# Cannot bypass security when trying to install Homebrew on new Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I am trying to install homebrew using:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

but then this error appears:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I tried adding -k:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSLk https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

but that still doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can download Homebrew script from your browser directly. All you need to do is:

open this `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh`

And save script to any folder then run this command in Terminal.

```
/bin/bash install.sh
```

Note: Don't forget to change directory to where downloaded script is available.

I will post more update if I find this curl problem fix. :)